# Is it possible to make sound faster?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

In my app I have a slider that when I move to one tick mark makes a "tick" sound.

Here is the function I call to make it:

```
func playSound() {
    if player.playing {
       player.stop()
    }

    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        self.player.prepareToPlay()
        self.player.play()
    })
}
```

However, what I would like to achieve is when a user drags slider faster the sound is faster...like "tick-tick-tick", something like you would hear when adjusting heat on the mechanical knob in a car.

With the implementation I have I can only get one "tick" sound on a fast drag, cause player.stop() cancels the previous one. So I was thinking if I can make that sound play faster when the dragging speed is faster?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase the rate by doing this:

```
self.player.prepareToPlay()
self.player.enableRate = true
self.player.rate = 2.0
self.player.play()
```

If you want to loop, you can add this:

```
self.player.numberOfLoops = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am overthinking that but here's how I would proceed:
You should create a `NSArray` containing as many `AVAudioPlayer` instances as your slider value. 
ie: if your slider range goes from 0 to 10, create an array with 10 AVAudioPlayer in it.

Once the user move the slider, go fetch for the `AVAudioPlayer` in your `NSArray` at the index of your slider value and play it. I would think carefully about the range of your slider as if the range is too low and the user move the slider too quickly you might run into the same issue that you have now.